# if a div that contain a specific text, how can i cancel the parent div jquery

Tags: jquery, contain

i have this issue
http://jsfiddle.net/valerioMassacci/LdCqX/

i have a specific div "comments" that onclick show me a set of elements
but if the another div contain a specific text: "anonymous", the entire div must be cancelled (not only not displayed)

the problem is that the jquery script find anoymous string and set the display:none; but don't work when i click on comments

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use "contains"

```
$("div:contains('Anonimo')")
```

http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/

Comment: i used it $(".comments-toggle:contains('Anonimo')").hide(); and as you can see from the example, it works. But after don't work when i click on comments..